# RabbitMQ API Queue stats issue

Tags: api, rabbitmq

I'm trying to understand how to use the stats to get the current queue size in rabbitmq.

I'm using this API endpoint: `/api/queues/vhost/name`. This is the stats I get (I've filtered some fields from the output).

```
...
  "message_stats": {
    "ack": 1,
    "ack_details": {
      "rate": 0.0
    },
    "deliver": 1,
    "deliver_details": {
      "rate": 0.0
    },
    "deliver_get": 1,
    "deliver_get_details": {
      "rate": 0.0
    },
    "deliver_no_ack": 0,
    "deliver_no_ack_details": {
      "rate": 0.0
    },
    "get": 0,
    "get_details": {
      "rate": 0.0
    },
    "get_empty": 0,
    "get_empty_details": {
      "rate": 0.0
    },
    "get_no_ack": 0,
    "get_no_ack_details": {
      "rate": 0.0
    },
    "publish": 1,
    "publish_details": {
      "rate": 0.0
    },
    "redeliver": 0,
    "redeliver_details": {
      "rate": 0.0
    }
  },
  "messages": 1,
...
```

My question is why is the `messages=1` when publish and ack count match. Shouldn't be `messages=0`?

Comment: You are correct, it should be 0. Did you query api as soon as message is consumed? Sometimes it takes a while to see correct numbers.

Comment: Yes, I query the API about 2 seconds after it is supposed to be consumed.